# Javascript : resize window not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resize the window . This is working fine on IE , but not working on Firefox and Chrome . Can you'll please help

```
<html>
<head>
<script LANGUAGE=javascript>
<!--
function orientWindow(){`
   `window.resizeTo(200,300)
   window.moveTo(400,400)
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
</head>

<BODY onLoad="javascript:orientWindow()">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty well supported, but you'll need to be resizing a window that your script opens, not the current window.

```
var w=window.open('','', 'width=100,height=100');
w.resizeTo(500,500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox (and Chrome and Safari) generally won't let a web page do that to the browser. I would be a little surprised if IE9 would allow it too.